# unable to find cxf-manifest.jar in cxf_home/lib

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I have generated wsdl file from tomcat. when i try to generate client stub from the wsdl using apache cxf 2.5.2 i got the unable to finde cxf-manifest.jar in cxf_home/lib. I already set environment variable for java_home, tomcat_home, cxf_home and cxf_jar. kindly help me to solve this problem.
this is the commend I have used in the command prompt ,.
 " wsdl2java -client -verbose http://localhost:8080/Service/Uploadfile?wsdl"

Answer (score 5):

Be sure you downloaded the BINARY distribution, not the SOURCE of apache CXF.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem under cygwin. If this is in your case, make sure you don't use cygwin paths (`/cygdrive/c/...`), but Windows (`"C:\Users\..."`) to set `CXF_HOME`.