# Unable to find cxf-manifest.jar in cxf_home/lib while using idl2wsdl conversion in cmd

Tags: java, web-services, environment-variables, corba, idl

ERROR: Unable to find `cxf-manifest.jar` in `cxf_home/lib` , While Using `idl2wsdl` conversion in cmd. I am getting these error.

I think, I have set all environment variable based on the requirement like

```
CXF_HOME
JAVA_HOME
CXF_JAR
TOOLS_JAR
```

How to solve this issue. Can anyone please help me out!!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to find cxf-manifest.jar in cxf\_home/lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782414/unable-to-find-cxf-manifest-jar-in-cxf-home-lib)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error by not setting up my classpath correctly. In windows, I created the following to fix the issue. I created/modified the following system variables.

CXF_HOME - C:\apache-cxf-3.1.10
Path - %CXF_HOME%\lib;%CXF_HOME%\bin